# Cannot Locate DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.DrawingShape Namespace in Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office

Tags: .net, ms-office, openxml-sdk

According to the [documentation for Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.office2010.word.drawingshape%28v=office.14%29.aspx) I should be able to use `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.DrawingShape` (along with many other namespaces prefixed by `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010`) with my Word 2010 document.

I have referenced assembly `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` (from `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` which is version 2.0 of the SDK) but Object Browser does not show any of the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010` etc namespaces as available.

If I reference Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office however, these namespaces are available.
Unfortunately, I need to use v2.0 in my project because we rely on a third party dll which is not compatible with framework 4.

Am I wrong to think that everything should be contained in `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` (for v2.0) or is there an additional package I need to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that Microsoft have sneaked in at least one update since I originally downloaded the SDK.
The version of the dll I was using was 2.0.4330.0 but after discussion with [Cindy Meister on an MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9fa87f73-0f18-4c37-8680-ee4dd445d457/cannot-reference-documentformatopenxmloffice2010worddrawingshape-namespace-using-open-xml-sdk?forum=oxmlsdk) I discovered that there is (at least one) newer version.

I downloaded the SDK again (my original download was probably a couple of years ago) and the version downloaded (v2.0.5022.0) magically contained the required namespaces.

I hope this helps someone as it's taken a ridiculous amount of time to sort this out.